# What is the equivalent of .height() and .width() of jQuery in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any equivalent cross browser API for getting the content height and width which don't include border size, padding and margin ? I don't have the option of using jQuery.

**Edit:** 
Forgot to mention, I have to support IE 8 too.

Comment: "I don't have the option of using jQuery" ah, ok, but why I see jquery tag then?

Comment: Even `jQuery` is pure JavaScript. What you probably want to say is "using the native DOM  API", and though it mostly follows common standard across browsers, it's ( some parts of it) not guaranteed to work cross-browser.

Comment: @nicael - for reaching people with knowledge of  "how jQuery implements things"

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh - yes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I have managed to come to a solution. For browsers except IE<9, `Window.getComputedStyle()` is to the rescue. *The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.* See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle for more details on that.

Problem is with IE 8 and earlier. `getComputedStyle` is `undefined` in them. Fortunately IE has proprietary `currentStyle` property from which we could retrieve content `width` and `height`. Sad but true that, if we declared `width` in `%` in stylesheets, it would return in `%` also.

So the problem remains is, we need a way to convert from percentage to pixel values. There is a [hack](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/#comment-102291) from **Dean Edwards** for solving this problem. Thanks to him !

```
    var PIXEL = /^\d+(px)?$/i;
    function getPixelValue(element, value) {
        if (PIXEL.test(value)) return parseInt(value);
        var style = element.style.left;
        var runtimeStyle = element.runtimeStyle.left;
        element.runtimeStyle.left = element.currentStyle.left;
        element.style.left = value || 0;
        value = element.style.pixelLeft;
        element.style.left = style;
        element.runtimeStyle.left = runtimeStyle;
        return value;
    };
```

So, finally the cross-browser solution of finding content width( logic for calculating height is same except query for height instead of width ) using the hack is as follows:

Suppose we have a `div` with id `'container'`. Its width is set as 50% in the style sheet.

```
 <style type="text/css">

    #container {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 5px;
    }

  </style>
```

Test  JavaScript Code:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
      var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(container, null)
      alert("width : "+computedStyle.width);
} else {
      alert("width : "+getPixelValue(container,container.currentStyle.width)+'px');
}
```

Comment: I would not even bother supporting IE8 and earlier if my target audience were China.

Comment: For anybody trying to use this and getting NaN: getComputedStyle will return auto for elements that have not (yet) been rendered. Sounds obvious but this of course includes display=none or if width was set to auto or the element is an inline element.

Comment: sadly not the same when box-sizing:  border-box; is present

Answer (score 7):

```
   document.getElementById("elemID").clientWidth;
   document.getElementById("elemID").clientHeight;
```

Here `elemID` is the element ID

Comment: it includes padding into calculation

Comment: if the element doesn't have padding this works perfectly though

Answer (score 4):

According to the http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ it's

`parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el, null).height.replace("px", ""))`

and

`parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el, null).width.replace("px", ""))`

for IE9+.

Comment: sadly not the same when box-sizing:  border-box; is present

Answer (score 1):

Usually offsetWidth and offsetHeight.

Comment: It includes border size and padding into width calculation

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR: `jQuery(window)` equivalent:

**WIDTH:** `jQuery(window).width()` => **`document.querySelector('html').clientWidth`**

<sub>or `document.body.clientWidth` with no horizontal scrollbar</sub>

**HEIGHT:** `jQuery(window).height()` => **`document.querySelector('html').clientHeight`**

---

I did some tests around this while rewriting old jQuery code and I want to mention
the equivalent of `$(window)` which does not (always) equal to <del>`window.clientWidth/Height`</del>!

### Example of a `window` dimensions (opened developer tools)

<sub>(example for a page opened in Chrome (v104))</sub>

#### A. WITH scrollbars (both vertical and horizontal)

```
#HTMLElement == document.querySelector('html')

          width                   |              height
jQuery(window).width():    1905   |   jQuery(window).height():      509
document.body.clientWidth: 1905   |   document.body.clientHeight: 14000
#HTMLElement.clientWidth:  1905   |   #HTMLElement.clientHeight:    509 // EQUAL to jQuery
window.innerWidth:         1920   |   window.innerHeight:           524
window.outerWidth:         1920   |   window.outerHeight:          1055
```

#### B. NO scrollbar (overflow hidden on body)

```
#HTMLElement == document.querySelector('html')

          width                   |              height
jQuery(window).width():    1920   |   jQuery(window).height():      524
document.body.clientWidth: 1920   |   document.body.clientHeight: 14000
#HTMLElement.clientWidth:  1920   |   #HTMLElement.clientHeight:    524 // still $ equal
window.innerWidth:         1920   |   window.innerHeight:           524 // only without SB
window.outerWidth:         1920   |   window.outerHeight:          1055
```

Now why did I include the `<html>` element there? That's because other width/height sources do not reflect the values from jQuery because they don't account for scrollbars.

### The core difference

**jQuery accounts for scrollbars**,

**native `window` properties do not**,

**however `html` `Element` does.**

Comment: If you used e.g. `$w` for `$(window)` just for width/height, this could be the drop in replacement: `const htmlEl = document.querySelector('html'); const $w = { width: () => htmlEl.clientWidth, height: () => htmlEl.clientHeight };` then you can call `$w.width()` / `$w.height()` and you would get jQuery's equals :-)

Comment: Also `$(document.querySelector('html')).scrollTop()` is the equivalent of jQuery's `$(window).scrollTop()` ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is innerWidth and innerHeight.

So something like

```
var obj = document.getElementById('idhere');
var width = obj.innerWidth...
```

Comment: internet explorer 8 will fail with this

Comment: So do internet explorer 7,6,5,4,3.

Comment: innerWidth is valid only for window object. On regular DOM elements like div, it is undefined

Answer (score -1):

Use this 
    document.getElementById("elementID").style.height;

Comment: Only if I set the style value earlier. This is pointless, because if I set it earlier, why do I need to query about it ?